# Putting an init method on an InLineFormSet

Tags: python, django, init

I have used an InLineFormSet to display all of the records that relate to a particular timesheet. The user can add many new forms on the page, I've used ajax and html to append an empty existing_form on the bottom with new IDs. However saving this is a problem.... because the newly added forms do not have timesheet_id assigned yet, they don't save as part of existing_forms.

I am trying to put an init method together to assign this when the form is created, hopefully solving this problem. (?)

1) Do I have to save the record before it will become part of existing_formset?

2) I have excluded the timesheet_id from the TimeForm.... this means I assume form.timesheet_id = var will not work... and I would have to use obj.timesheet_id... but can I do this in the init of a form?? very confused.

3) Is it easier to use a new formset for newly added forms and use modelformset_factory.....

View:

```
class CustomInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        super(CustomInlineFormSet, self).clean()
        timesheet = TimeSheet.objects.get(pk=timesheet_id)
        for form in self.forms:
            form.empty_permitted = True
    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomInlineFormSet, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        # the following won't work because it's excluded from the form?
        # self.fields['timesheet_id'] = forms....... oh no
        timesheet_fromview = request.session.get('timesheet')
        print timesheet_fromview
        for form in self.forms:
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.timesheet_id = timesheet_fromview

        try:
            del request.session['timesheet']
            print "session deleted"
        except KeyError:
            pass
            print "Key error raised"



def timesheet(request, timesheet_id):
    timesheet = TimeSheet.objects.get(pk=timesheet_id)

    TimeInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(TimeSheet, Time, exclude=('timesheet_id',), extra=0, formset=CustomInlineFormSet)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # instance is not yet timesheet.... no foreign key in new fields so doesn't do anything
        existing_formset = TimeInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=timesheet)

        for thetime in existing_formset.forms:
            # obj = thetime.save(commit=False)
            # obj.timesheet_id = timesheet
            # obj.save()
            # print obj
            if thetime.is_valid():
                print "existing time is valid"
                thetime.save()
            else:
                "existing time is not valid"

        context = {
            "timesheet": timesheet,
            "existing_formset": existing_formset,
        }    
        return render(request, 'tande/timesheet.html', context)
    else:
        print "method is not post"
        existing_formset = TimeInlineFormSet(instance=timesheet)
        new_timeformset = NewTimeFormSet()
        request.session['timesheet'] = timesheet
        context = {
            "timesheet": timesheet,
            "existing_formset": existing_formset,
        }    
        return render(request, 'tande/timesheet.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've approached this by using two separate formsets in my views, one inline for existing records and one modelformset for new additions. I then save the two separately with a field that is True when the record is a new addition, and False when it is in the existing formset:

```
class Time(models.Model):
    project_id = models.ForeignKey(Project, null=True)
    date_worked = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    hours = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    timesheet_id = models.ForeignKey(TimeSheet, null=True)
    add_row = models.CharField(max_length=10, default=True, editable=False)
    def __unicode__ (self):
        return self.description
```

The view saves the two formsets separately:

```
def timesheet(request, timesheet_id):
    timesheet = TimeSheet.objects.get(pk=timesheet_id)

    TimeInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(TimeSheet, Time, exclude=('timesheet_id',), extra=0, formset=CustomInlineFormSet)
    NewTimeFormSet = modelformset_factory(Time, form=TimeForm, formset=RequiredFormSet)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        existing_formset = TimeInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=timesheet)
        newtime_formset = NewTimeFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)

        for orange in newtime_formset:
            obj = orange.save(commit=False)
            if obj.add_row == "True":
                obj.timesheet_id = timesheet
                obj.add_row = "False"
                obj.save()

        for thetime in existing_formset.forms:
            if thetime.is_valid():
                thetime.save()

        existing_formset = TimeInlineFormSet(instance=timesheet)
        newtime_formset = NewTimeFormSet()
        context = {
            "timesheet": timesheet,
            "existing_formset": existing_formset,
            "newtime_formset": newtime_formset,
        }    
        return render(request, 'tande/timesheet.html', context)
```